# Suddenly cannot edit document properties inside of document set

Tags: document, document-set, properties

I created a document set content type with meta data/columns, and configured the "document" content type for a particular library with different meta data/columns.

When I set it up last week, users could edit the properties of documents inside the document set (either with the properties box or with quick edit).

A user this week reported it isn't working, and now that I've checked it out, it seems now the properties cannot be edited. It displays "saving" and then just reverts to the default value.

This is driving me crazy as I cannot figure out how to fix this, as it was working great last week. Can anyone make any recommendations? Do I maybe need to add the document columns to the document set itself?

Comment: Here is a nice article on [document set](https://sharepointmaven.com/document-sets-hidden-gem-sharepoint/) that I would recommend to resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you check the permissions on the library itself? Did you try to create another library just for testing and add this content to it to see if it's a behavior on the whole site? If it's not replicated on the whole site, try creating another doc set content type and add it to the library and see if it works, just to limit the possibilities.